# What code can be adapted to parse a podcast RSS or iTunes XML feed and deliver the *latest* MP3 file?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-development, rss, podcast

I am looking for some app I can run on a server (hosted website or some other service) or link from it, that will deliver the latest podcast file from an RSS feed or iTunes XML feed in this simple way:

A link to: `http://server.com/script?http://podcastfeedurl`

Will send back/deliver: Latest MP3 file parsed from the feed

My use case is that I want to simply link to -just- the latest podcast file from my 1 Radio News Android app and web site - http://1radionews.com - and have it play.

There are a handful of world news broadcasters that provide a static MP3 file - http://1radionews.com/radio-news-on-demand-hourly-news/ - that I include in my app on-demand. But many radio news sites just have a podcast feed for their hourly news casts or daily English language programming.

As I am trying to provide the absolute quickest uncomplicated way to play the latest news from great news radio sources without needing a relatively complicated podcasting app, I figure with the right code/web-app, served from the right place I can help people get to the freshest news.

I imagine the software service running on my basic Linux web-hosted site (Hostgator) or some other site well suited to running the service ... I am open. I have thought about code being built into my app, but if this is web-based I can use with my app (it can play a simple mp3 file on-demand and many web stream powered by ffmpeg) and my website. If I can simply put the podcast feed into the URL and end up with a resulting MP3 file being delivered back my existing app can just play the file as could a web browser for that matter.

Here are example feeds I'd like to parse: [BBC](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/worldservice/globalnews/rss.xml), [Marketplace](http://www.marketplace.org/node/all/podcast.xml).

#### Requirements summed up:

- web-app or web-service
- something I can host on my Linux server or a web-service I can link to
- parses RSS ot iTunes feeds
- returns the newest item of the parsed feed
- feed URL can be passed to it in a simple way

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but this video shows just how simple it is to play the latest headlines from static MP3 files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEGAVRVo5Pw

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback, Steven! Remember you can always [edit] your post to improve it – and in fact should do so especially when providing additional details (they might get lost in comments). I've done that for you, and also adjusted a few words to prevent your question from being "closed" for being off-topic (the "code" thingy). Please check if it fits your needs this way; if so, please also delete the comments which I already integrated (makes it easier to deal with the question). Wish you good luck and good answers – fingers crossed!

Comment: PS: Maybe someone knows a library you could use. I take it that would be acceptable as well (to integrate in your app). For that it would be useful to know what programming language your app uses (PHP? Perl? Python?)